# Passing the icon name inside a widget to a variable

Tags: flutter, widget, icons

How can I pass an icon directly to abstract class Widget extends ? I'm trying to create this widget, but it doesn't support me putting the icon name in a string and passing it inside the icon (icons)

```
              buildTextFormField(
              "Email teste", emailController, "usuario@imodulo.com",
              ),

    
Widget buildTextFormField(
  String label,
  TextEditingController c,
  String hintText,
  String icone,
) {
  return TextFormField(
    controller: c,
    autofocus: true,
    obscureText: true,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: label,
      **prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.'$icone'),**
      hintText: hintText,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Why not just pass it as [IconData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IconData-class.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into `Icon`s you discover that they are just indices into a font. So, in fact icons don't really have 'names' they have numbers.

Here's a random example:

```
  static const IconData checklist = IconData(0xe15b, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
```

So, rather than trying to instantiate the icon using the name 'checklist', you could instead use its number `0xe15b`.

Where ever you were going to store the icon's name (a database? the backend?), instead store a number, and you code becomes:

```
  prefixIcon: Icon(IconData(icone, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
```

Answer (score 0):

I passed an iconData parameter

```
Widget buildTextFormField(
  String label,
  TextEditingController c,
  String hintText,
  **IconData icone,**
) {
  return TextFormField(
    controller: c,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: label,
      **prefixIcon: Icon(icone),**
      hintText: hintText,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: You accepted another anser already, so there is no need to answer it yourself. I guess you wanted to show your solution based on that answer to help others which is nice. Either write this as a comment for the acceptated answer or put it at the end of your question. Take care to add a good explanation what you are showing since the current one is not easy to understand.